# SAS Enterprise Guide Query Builder vs Code

Tags: sas, query-builder, enterprise-guide

I currently have a query builder set up to create computed columns that then create a dataset.  I also want to include traffic lighting to the final data set.  I only know how to do traffic lighting using code so I opened up the query builder code to edit it.  It said that it could not be edited and that a copy could be made to edit. I created a copy, appended the traffic lighting code and ran the process.  Now, whenever I have to make a change to the query builder (for example: editing a computed column) I have to then manually go into the SAS code and edit that.  Is there a way that when the query builder is edited that it can automatically flow into the SAS code that I also want to type out? Or is there an easier way all together to go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a code node that does your traffic lighting, and attach it in the flow after the query node. That way the two things are independent and a change to one does not affect the other.

Comment: Currently, traffic lighting IS in a separate node. I'm trying to make it so that they are dependent and a change to the query builder changes the code in the node that is traffic lighting